# In PrimeNG, how do I display a spinner when waiting for a resolver within a module?

Tags: angular, module, spinner, primeng, resolver

I'm using PrineNG 14.  In my main app routes file, I set a path to load a module ...

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./products/products.module').then(m => m.ProductsModule)
  }
];
```

In my module, I have this resolver setup for a route ...

```
const routes: Routes = [
    ...
  {
    path: 'products',
    component: MyHomeComponent,
    resolve:{
      proudcts:ProductsResolve
    }
  } 
]
```

I would like to haev a spinner show while the component is loading (i.e. while the resolver is still getting the data)

```
<p-progressSpinner></p-progressSpinner>
```

However, I'm unsure where to put the spinner.

Comment: Spinner should be at `app.component.html`

Answer (score 0):

The resolver prevents a component to load. so you can't put the spinner inside the component that you resolved.
but you can put it in on a parent component.
the resolver will send a flag to a shared service where the process starts, and add a finalize rxjs pipe to change the flag to false.
in the parent component, you can listen to this flag.

```
 resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    this.sharedService.componentIsLoad$.next(true);
    return this.appSrvice.checkSomething().pipe(
        finalize(() =>  this.sharedService.componentIsLoad$.next(false))
   )
}
```

in the parent component you listen to this flag:

```
<p-progressSpinner *ngIf="componentIsLoad$ | async"></p-progressSpinner>
```

Comment: How is "this.sharedService" defined?

Comment: Just add there a BehaviorSubject<boolean> componentIsLoad$

Comment: If there are multiple resolvers for a specific route, woudl I be adding this code to each of the resolvers?  Also what if the resolver is used in multiple routes?

Comment: you can use with the service but instead of passing to it a boolean you can pass a key to identify which spinner to play

Comment: Ok, I will consider this approach.  However, I feel like it is good practice to keep the resolver "pure" (only having code related to retrieving the data) and spinner logic would go at a component/router level.  But I'm no expert at Angular so I coudl be wrong.

Comment: It's totally ok to use a resolver for the loading spinner